# where to buy breadboard terminal strips

Tags: breadboard

I want to 3D print my own customised breadboards but I can't seem to find a place that sells the small metal clips on the back of the breadboard.
Just wondering if anybody would know a store online that sells them.

Comment: Why not simply buy cheap breadboards directly from China (Ebay, Ali) and use it as a source for the metal clips.

Comment: Yes. It seems that it’s just easier to buy cheap breadboards and use the clips from those.

Answer (score 2):

[Aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000287920452.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.13001d93o62ndu&algo_pvid=625bf6ca-6149-450a-b0b4-1eae22307c92&algo_expid=625bf6ca-6149-450a-b0b4-1eae22307c92-6&btsid=0bb0623d16064676868841849e992d&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) sells [breadboard terminals strips](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000502561020.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.13001d93o62ndu&algo_pvid=625bf6ca-6149-450a-b0b4-1eae22307c92&algo_expid=625bf6ca-6149-450a-b0b4-1eae22307c92-8&btsid=0bb0623d16064676868841849e992d&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) in the form of pcbs, although you might have to wait a bit longer and buy them in bulk.

[Amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/Adafruit-Perma-Proto-Half-sized-Breadboard-PCB/dp/B00SK8QR8S) sells the same components but pricier